# Marker icon always default

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using Leaflet to display a map in an ionic app and I am using https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers to enable clustering.

I can't seem to get my custom icon to display though, i always get the blue default.

First I create the markerClusterGroup

```
  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
    showCoverageOnHover: true,
    zoomToBoundsOnClick: true
  });
```

Then I create the Icon:

```
  var myIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '<myiconurl.png>'
  });
```

I then populate the markers array by looping through an array of objects I need to display on the map, and bind a pop[up to each marker too.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arrayOfVenues.length; i++) {
    var name = $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].name;
    var id = $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].venueID;
    var image = $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].venueImageURL;
    var distanceTo = "4 Miles Away";
    var popupContent = "<div style='height:200px;width:100%;position:relative;cursor:pointer;z-index:999999' nav-transition='ios' onclick='window.navDetails(" + id + ")'><img style='object-fit: cover;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;' height='200' width='100%' src='" + image + "'/><h3 style='color:#FFFFFF !important;position:absolute;z-index:100;bottom:3vh;left:14px;font-size:3vh;'>" + name + "</h3><h3 style='color:#FFFFFF !important;position:absolute;z-index:100;bottom:0;left:14px;font-size:2.5vh;'>" + distanceTo + "</h3></div>"
    markers.addLayer(L.marker([
      $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].latitude,
      $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].longitude, {
        title: $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].name,
        riseOnHover: true,
        icon:myIcon
      }
    ]).bindPopup(popupContent, {
      maxWidth: 300,
      minWidth: 300,
      minHeight: 300,
      maxHeight: 300
    }));
    debugger
  }
   mymap.addLayer(markers);
```

Once displayed on the map, everything works okay except i still have the default marker icons.

Any tips?

Comment: `'<myiconurl.png>'` looks like a placeholder, or is it literal?

Comment: Sorry, i just took out the URL to post on here!

Comment: Ah, okay. Another thing: `myIcon` is actually `barIcon`?

Comment: Sorry, edited - I must be more careful when sanitising SO posts. Its been a long day!

Comment: It would be best to provide a self-contained, runnable example. Easier for us to play around with the code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from looking at the code, I believe a closing bracket is misplaced:

```
markers.addLayer(L.marker([
  $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].latitude,
  $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].longitude
], {
    title: $scope.arrayOfVenues[i].name,
    riseOnHover: true,
    icon:myIcon
  }
)
```

Comment: You absolute saint. Even when i present you with confused, unhelpful code you still find the solution. Thank you!!